# How to install the Java JDK offline?

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, offline

I would like to install the Java JDK on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 that will never have access to the internet, but can have a file transferred from another computer with internet access. I looked at multiple guides, but none of them worked for me fully. What would be the steps to install the Java JDK offline?

Comment: I asked this question last time and it got taken off for the reason
"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.” 
The Java JDK is used primarily for programming and installing it is the first step for many people programming with Java.

Comment: I struggled to find a way to install completely offline and what I finally arrived at was a combination of solutions I found. I would like to post this for other people having trouble finding a straightforward solution.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the oracle jdk from another computer, put it on a thumb drive and transferred it over to my offline system.
Then I ran these commands:

```
  sudo mkdir /usr/local/java
  sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
  sudo mv jdk1.8.0_121 /usr/local/java/
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javac" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javaws" 1
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
  sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
  sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I am open to suggestions if it isn't the best way to go about this, but this worked. My solution referenced this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENF3lepcg_o). However, I had to make some changes, mainly going a folder deeper than bin in the update alternatives step, and the addition of the chmod, chown steps.

Comment: A similar way is detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712399/installing-java-offline) on AskUbuntu. Future readers can check it out if they want more detailed information.